# Eloquent DB class is null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

When I try to use he DB class of eloquent i get this error :

```
Call to a member function raw() on null
```

Code :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
...
DB::raw("count(id_annonce)")
...
```

I already tried updating composer and frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this: https://jenssegers.com/using-eloquent-without-laravel

You have to use `Capsule` to init the DB connection and boot eloquent. Anyway you can use an alias to call it `DB` if you prefere.

Comment: already made capsule =/
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection(array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'spectacles',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'root',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => ''
));
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();

Comment: Try to use `Capsule::raw` instead of `DB::raw`

Comment: sadly, the link you give is 404 :(

Comment: @AndyPreston this is the correct link: https://jenssegers.com/using-eloquent-without-laravel

I've updated the answer too :) Thank you